# Gradient of a neuronal network

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, gradienttape

I have a trained neural network that predicts the noise of a given image.
Now I want to use it to calculate a subgradient of my NN wrt the norm of the output.

I want to use this in a larger algorithm, but since I can not get it to work as expected, I created this minimal example.

```
model = load_model(os.path.join(nn_path, 'NN' + name +'.h5')) #trained NN
y0_tensor = np.load(os.path.join(data_path, 'fbp_val' + name +'.npy'))[0] #typical input of the NN

max_iter = 15
alpha = 0.45
s = 0.2

for iters in range(max_iter):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(y0_tensor)
        prediction = model(y0_tensor)
        norm = tf.norm(prediction)

    grad = tape.gradient(norm, y0_tensor)   #d norm / d y0_tensor

    y0_tensor = y0_tensor - s * alpha * grad
```

I expected it to become more and more similar to the output of the NN with an increasing number of iterations. But it just seems to add noise to it.

Note that I am not fixed on using GardientType. I also tried to use `keras.backend.gradients` with no success.

For more background information, here is what I am trying to do:

> Note that the subgradient of the regularization term can be evaluated
> by standard software for network training with the backpropagation
> algorithm.
> (Source: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6420/ab6d57, chapter 4.2)